# JQuery how to get <title> of a generated html

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a whole html document in a variable but I don't know how to get the title. Tryied the code below but it only works for specific divs and I don't know why.

```
//valid html
var data='<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8" /><title>MyTitle</title><meta name="description" content="MyDEsc" /></head><body><div id="header">header content</div><div class="container" id="wrapper">Default body<div id="home">home</div><div id="project"><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div></div></div></body></html>'

console.log($(data).find('title').text()) //nothing
console.log($('title', $(data)).text()) //nothing
console.log('header :' + $('#header', $(data)).html()) //undefined
console.log('header :' + $('#home', $(data)).html()) //expected value
console.log('project :' + $('#project', $(data)).html()) //expected value
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/22RLk/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your html, head, and body tags are stripped out so what you end up with is a collection of elements rather than a full document. The title is one of those elements.

```
console.log($(data).filter('title').text())
```

http://jsfiddle.net/22RLk/3/

If you want to create a document you can use

```
document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(data)
```

[create a javascript document Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051962/create-a-javascript-document-object)
[How to create Document objects with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227612/how-to-create-document-objects-with-javascript)

Comment: any way to have a full document?

Answer (score 2):

I would use Regexp for this, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/maximgladkov/6TTF5/1/

```
console.log(data.match(/<title>(.+?)<\/title>/)[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure Javascript:

```
console.log('title :' + data.substr(data.indexOf('<title>') + 7,data.indexOf('</title>')-7-data.indexOf('<title>')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).find('title').text()
$(document).find('title').html()
```

Try that way